# Change xml file node value for SOAP request in vb.net

Tags: xml, vb.net, soap

i need to send XML file(SOAP+xml) to webservice, but i need to change 2 node value in the XML file. Here is the XML file :

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns2826:get_order_data xmlns:ns2826="http://tempuri.org">
<periode>
<tgl1 xsi:type="xsd:string">Date 1</tgl1>
<tgl2 xsi:type="xsd:string">Date 2</tgl2>
</periode>
</ns2826:get_order_data>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I need to change Date 1 and Date 2 into datetime value. So far i have tried to change the xml file like this :

```
    Sub requestByDate()
        'edit file xml sebelum request'
        Dim myXmlDocument As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
        myXmlDocument.Load("C:\xmlRequest\requestOrderdata.xml")

        Dim node As XmlNode
        node = myXmlDocument.DocumentElement

        Dim node2 As XmlNode 'Used for internal loop.'

        For Each node In node.ChildNodes
            For Each node2 In node.ChildNodes
                'MsgBox(node2.InnerText)'
                If node2.Name = "ns2826:get_order_data" Then
                   Dim newkey As String

                    newkey = "<" & "periode" & ">" & vbCrLf
                    newkey = newkey & "<" & "tgl1 xsi:type=" & ControlChars.Quote & "xsd:string" & ControlChars.Quote & ">10/06/2015 01:00:00</tgl1>" & vbCrLf
                    newkey = newkey & "<tgl2 xsi:type=" & ControlChars.Quote & "xsd:string" & ControlChars.Quote & ">10/06/2015 03:00:00</tgl2>" & vbCrLf
                    newkey = newkey & "</periode>"

                    MsgBox("Old Key = " & node2.InnerText & Strings.Chr(9) & "New key = " & newkey)
                    node2.InnerText = newkey
                    myXmlDocument.Save("C:\xmlRequest\requestOrderData2.xml")


                End If
                Next
            Next
            'selesai edit'
    End Sub
```

but it didn't work as the new xml file is not a valid XML request file(if i run the program with this new xml file as request, it return "there are multiple root elements").
Is there any other way to change the Date 1 and Date 2 value?

Comment: what version of .NET framework are you using?

Comment: Then `XDocument` is available for you. See my answer for example on how to use `XDocument`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into newer API [`XDocument`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to replace your `XmlDocument` approach, for example :

```
Dim doc = XDocument.Load("C:\xmlRequest\requestOrderdata.xml")
Dim ns2826 As XNamespace = "http://tempuri.org"

'find and update <tgl1>'
Dim tgl1 = doc.Descendants(ns2826 + "get_order_data").Elements("periode").Elements("tgl1").First
tgl1.Value = "10/06/2015 01:00:00"

'find and update <tgl2>'
Dim tgl2 = doc.Descendants(ns2826 + "get_order_data").Elements("periode").Elements("tgl2").First
tgl2.Value = "10/06/2015 03:00:00"

doc.Save("C:\xmlRequest\requestOrderData2.xml")
```

You can also use [XML axis](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384769.aspx) syntax which available in VB, for example :

```
Imports <xmlns:ns2826="http://tempuri.org">

.....

'find <tgl1>'
Dim tgl1 = doc...<ns2826:get_order_data>.<periode>.<tgl1>.First

'find <tgl2>'
Dim tgl2 = doc...<ns2826:get_order_data>.<periode>.<tgl2>.First
```

Comment: thank u for your kind answer @har07, using your example i get 2 error on  First("tgl1") and First("tgl2"). the error message is :

Error 1 Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to 'System.Func(Of System.Xml.Linq.XElement, Boolean)'
do you know what might be the problem?